# How to use Anonymous class in java Eclipse in right way?

Tags: java, eclipse, class, anonymous

I am a beginner and trying to learn java recently I learned the Anonymous class and tried to create something  but this syntax is not working for me but the syntax is the same in the tutorial

can anyone please help me to get it right
this is my code...

```
package ClassesAndObject;

class Example {

    public void fun1() {
        System.out.print("This is parent class Example");
    }

    Example a = new Example() {

        public void funt1() {
            System.out.print("This is ananymous class ");

        }

    };

}

public class annonymousClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example e1 = new Example();

        e1.a.fun1();

    }

}
```

thtis is the error i am getting....[image]

Comment: When you create an instance of `Example`, the `a` field is initialized by creating an instance of `Example`. To do that, it needs to initialize the `a` field by creating an instance of `Example`. To do that, it needs to initialize the `a` field by creating an instance of `Example`. See the problem?

Comment: Extra marks for the unintended shout-out to XKCD: https://xkcd.com/1188/

Comment: @AndyTurner actually I kind of get it you just can't create anonymous inside the same class  which instance you are creating ......and then you need to make an instance of the class where you created the anonymous class .....

Comment: @HarshTripathi-blue it is nothing specific to anonymous classes. The same happens with `class A { A a = new A(); }`